# Determine the view count for specific page in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Do anyone knows how to do the View count for a specific page. Like in StackOverflow, in the question list you would see the View count which describes how many times the question was viewed.

I would like to know how to do this in asp.net mvc.
I already have an idea but im not sure if right.

I need an expert advice... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to do this is to log the number of times a page is requested in a database.
You can then add a property to your domain object which can be populated in the normal manner by your data access layer, e.g.

```
public class Question
{
    public int HitCount { get; set; }
}
```

You can then display this in your page.

Comment: Hi Adam,
But i don't want to increment the hitcount for the user that already viewed the page before.. only for new user. Does that mean i should also log the Ip adress of the user to determine if he already view the page?

Comment: Logging only one hit per user is going to be more difficult and, if you are allowing anonymous access, perhaps even impossible. If your website insists on a user being logged in, then you can log only one hit per username for the page and use the method I describe above for displaying it to the user. If, however, you allow anonymous access, then the only identifer you have is the IP address. Imagine a corporation with 1,000 employees who all access the internet through a single proxy. You would effectively log only one hit even though all 1,000 people might request the page.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is a VERY good tool, when used properly.